# Black screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to 14.04 from the updater, and the installation seemed to go fine. When my HP Pavilion boots up, it gets to the login screen and everything looks normal. It allows me to login, but then it goes to a black screen.  When I press Ctrl+Alt+F6 I can login from the command prompt. It gives me the following message:

```
no talloc stack frame at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like samba related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186

Multiple users posted comments at the bug report, reporting success by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass
```

After a quick google search: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214042. That thread may help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that before and oddly something that sometimes works is to press ctrl-alt-F1 followed immediately by ctrl-alt-F7.

I have one old laptop computer here which developed that problem after upgrading from ubuntu 8.04LTS to 10.04LTS, and that sequence of key combinations was my solution.  I soon grew to appreciate it because it meant that absolutely nobody but me could use that computer. ;-)